# Does elastic beanstalk have build in antivirus?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am registering my database in my country office. One of the questions in their application form is about the antivirus of the server. As a server for application, I use Elastic `Amazon Linux 2016.09`. Does this environment have a built in antivirus?

If the question is no, I would appriciate any guides on how to enable/install it.

Thanks!

Comment: This question might belong on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 2):

No. Amazon Linux (and, if fact, all/most Linux distributions) do not have anti-virus software installed. Anti-virus is common for Windows systems, but is relatively uncommon for Linux systems.

You could obtain anti-virus products from the [AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/), commercial vendors or open-source repositories (eg [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/)).